# Implementation of containsKey HashMap<> - Java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

The whole purpose of using containsKey() is to check whether any given key is already in HashMap or not? If it doesn't contain that key than just add key into that HasMap.

> But seems like when we call this method it's parameters are Object
>   type that means, containsKey() checks whether given argument(key) has
>   similar memory address with any other already entered key.

Potential Solution:

> One solution could be get a unique data from that object1(oldKey) and
>   check with object2(new key), If they are same than don't use it in
>   HashMap. However this means containsKey has no purpose at all. Am I
>   right?

Sorry I am not ranting, or probably I sound like one. But I would like to know the most efficient way to get over this problem.

will be thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make much sense at the moment. What problem are you talking about, what are you trying to achieve, where does "If not than don't add it" come from?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. How does "Object type" somehow imply that it checks of "similar memory address"?

Comment: You should not think in terms of memory addresses in Java. Instead, think about references. And please explain what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry question is vaguely written :(, But I guess below given answer's satisfied me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But seems like when we call this method it's parameters are Object type that means, containsKey() checks whether given argument(key) has similar memory address with any other already entered key.

Wrong. Their equality is checked by comparing their `hashCode()` values first. Only if the hash values are equal, the objects themselves may be compared (but always using `equals()`, not `==`). So any class where these two methods are implemented properly will work correctly as a key in a `HashMap`.

Comment: sorry about vaguely written question, But your answer certainly helped. Thanks!

Comment: Strange. What would the point of comparison beyond hashCode be? if the hashCodes do match we cannot be guaranteed that the data will likewise be equal? I guess maybe there are people out there overriding the hashCode function please send me their addresses so I may smack them in about the face with a rubber chicken!

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap.containsKey()` methods finds if whether the key's `hashCode()` exists and not by equality comparison. If the hash code exists, it will pull the entry to see if the reference equality OR `equals()` of the key is equal.

This is implemented in `HashMap.getEntry()` method:

```
/**
     * Returns the entry associated with the specified key in the
     * HashMap.  Returns null if the HashMap contains no mapping
     * for the key.
     */
    final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
        int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
        for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
             e != null;
             e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return e;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> But seems like when we call this method it's parameters are Object
>   type

Yes, but the method will be called on the actual implementation type, not on Object.class. That's why it's so important to implement hashCode() properly.

Read: [Effective java, Item 9](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA45#v=snippet&q=hashCode&f=false) (in fact you should buy and read the whole book)

Answer (score 0):

> But seems like when we call this method it's parameters are Object type that means, containsKey() checks whether given argument(key) has similar memory address with any other already entered key

This conclusion is wrong. The `containskey(Object key)` calls the `equals()` method on the passed key , so if this has overriden the `equals(Object key)` method , then it will resolve correctly based on the key equivalence criteria. Ofcourse if the Key has not overridden the `equals()` method , then it is a bad design to start with.

Comment: No, it calls `hashCode` first of all (and after that, *sometimes* `equals` too).